# C++ giving me 2 different answers to basic calculation

Tags: c++

When I run this I get the right answer outside of the if statement, and the wrong one inside the if statement.. 
EX 3 and 3 for length and width gives me 9 but inside condition it gives me 92..
I have tried double float int... 
Any help would be great...

```
cout << "you entered 2 for Rectangle\n";
cout << "Enter the length of the Rectangle.\n";
cin >> lengthRec;

cout << "Enter the width of the Rectangle.\n";
cin >> widthRec;

areaRec = lengthRec * widthRec;
cout << areaRec;

if ((lengthRec > 0) && (widthRec > 0)) {
    areaRec = lengthRec * widthRec;
    cout << "\nlength is " << lengthRec << "\n"<< "width is " << 
    widthRec << "\n";
    cout << "The area is ";
    cout << areaRec;
}
else {
    cout << "Invalid entry, Please re run with a positive number\n";
}
```

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73101508f1a55aaf). Please post your actual code. It's likely that, since you didn't write a newline after `areaRec`, something later in your program writes out a "2" and the two numbers appear next to each other.

Comment: It looks like code inside the `if` statement is working correctly, printing 9 and 2 gets printed somewhere later. Try changing `cout << areaRec;` to `cout << areaRec << " Garbage:"`; and you see what I mean.

Comment: Ahhh.... Thanks so much, I had a choice check in the bottom of the code and that is what was causing this... Thank you all so much!! my first question and I was nervous...

Comment: The `if` statement has too many parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine no issues - something else later tampers the o/p line since you don;t have '\n'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int lengthRec, widthRec, areaRec;
    cout << "you entered 2 for Rectangle\n";
    cout << "Enter the length of the Rectangle.\n";
    cin >> lengthRec;

    cout << "Enter the width of the Rectangle.\n";
    cin >> widthRec; //CHECK HERE

    areaRec = lengthRec * widthRec;
    cout << areaRec<<"\n";

    if ((lengthRec > 0) && (widthRec > 0)) {

        areaRec = lengthRec * widthRec;
        cout << "\nlength is " << lengthRec << "\n"<< "width is " << 
        widthRec << "\n";
        cout << "The area is ";
        cout << areaRec<<"\n"; //CHECK HERE
    }
    else {
        cout << "Invalid entry, Please re run with a positive number\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:-

```
you entered 2 for Rectangle
Enter the length of the Rectangle.
Enter the width of the Rectangle.
9
length is 3
width is 3
The area is 9
```

Comment: Saying that it works correctly is not an answer. If you want to show a demo, post a link to a site like ideone.com or rextester.com in a comment.

Comment: @Barmar: Got it!